# How to hide a property of custom collection while using DataGridView DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a custom collection let's say

```
MyClass
{
    prop Name;
    prop Address;
    prop isRequired;
}


MyCustomCollection : List<MyClass>
{

}
```

When I do

```
MyCustomCollection collection = new  MyCustomCollection ();
datagridView.DataSource = collection;
```

The datagridview is populated with three columns Name, address , isRequired..

I want to hide isRequired property from the datagrid view how can i do that...

and also I want to use it as a property to check in another classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can set the visible property of the column to false.
For each set of business data I want to display, I keep track of the # of leftmost-columns I want hidden because they hold PK values.
Here's a sample:

```
        dgvDisplaySet.DataSource = _setSource
    gridColsToHide = _displaySet.hidePKFields
    For gridCol = 0 To dgvDisplaySet.Columns.Count - 1
        dgvDisplaySet.Columns(gridCol).Visible = (gridCol >= gridColsToHide)
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [Browsable(false)]

MyClass
{
     prop Name; 
   prop Address;
   [Browsable(false)]
    prop isRequired;
}
to hide the column

Answer (score 1):

the Browsable attribute is a good option indeed. You could also set AutoGenerateColumns to false and create the columns manually...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting another option Thomas.
Thomas, is there is any way so that I can make particular rows read only . If suppose I want to make those rows read only whose IsRequired property is false in MyClass

Comment: There is a way to do this, by handling the CellBeginEdit event. In the handler, you check whether the row can be edited, and cancel the event (e.Cancel = true) if it can't